# Python: Reshaping the JSON After Pull

Tags: python, json, list, rest, dictionary

I've been struggling with this problem long enough on my own and lost productivity.

I am using python to open a session with an api and extract it's data. the URL is in the form

```
http://api.kivaws.org/v1/teams/2/loans.json
```

where the "2" placeholder in the path signifies the team ID and the pages loaded are all of the loans a team has made. Don't worry about what this means; just know that my code modifies this url to iterate through the teams. In fact, here is the code;

```
import urllib.request as urllib
import json
import time

team_loans = {}

url = "http://api.kivaws.org/v1/teams/"
#Teams ultimately 1- 11885
for i in range(1, 4):
params = dict(
    id = i
)

try:
    handle = urllib.urlopen(str(url+str(i)+"/loans.json"))
except:
    print("Could not handle url")
    continue
# reading response
item_html =  handle.read().decode('utf-8')
# converting bytes to str
data = str(item_html)
# converting to json
data = json.loads(data)
# getting number of pages to crawl
numPages = data['paging']['pages']
# deleting paging data
data.pop('paging')
#Put these items in a list and iterate through indices for boolean check
#data is a dictionary, with a list object inside for each team
for item in data['loans']:
        del item['name']
        del item['lender_count']
        del item['loan_amount']
        del item['sector']
        del item['description']
        del item['status']
        del item['funded_amount']
        del item['image']
        del item['activity']
        del item['use']
        del item['location']
        del item['posted_date']
        del item['borrower_count']
        del item['bonus_credit_eligibility']
        del item['tags']
        try:
            del item['basket_amount']
        except:
            pass
        try:
            del item['planned_expiration_date']
        except:
            pass
        try:
            del item['themes']
        except:
            pass
        try:
            del item['currency_exchange_loss_amount']
        except:
            pass
        try:
            del item['video']
        except:
            pass
        item['team_id'] = i

#More than one page
if numPages > 1:
    for pa in range(2,numPages + 1,1):
        handle = urllib.urlopen(str(url+str(i)+"/loans.json?page="+str(pa)))
        print("Pulling loan data from team " + str(i) + "...")
        # reading response
        item_html =  handle.read().decode('utf-8')
        # converting bytes to str
        datatemp = str(item_html)
        # converting to json
        datatemp = json.loads(datatemp)
        #print(datatemp)
        datatemp.pop('paging')
        #Put these items in a list and iterate through indices for boolean check
        for item in datatemp['loans']:
                del item['name']
                del item['lender_count']
                del item['loan_amount']
                del item['sector']
                del item['description']
                del item['status']
                del item['funded_amount']
                del item['image']
                del item['activity']
                del item['use']
                del item['location']
                del item['posted_date']
                del item['borrower_count']
                del item['bonus_credit_eligibility']
                del item['tags']
                try:
                    del item['basket_amount']
                except:
                    pass
                try:
                    del item['planned_expiration_date']
                except:
                    pass
                try:
                    del item['themes']
                except:
                    pass
                try:
                    del item['currency_exchange_loss_amount']
                except:
                    pass
                try:
                    del item['video']
                except:
                     pass
                item['team_id'] = i

        # adding data to initial list
        for loan in datatemp['loans']:
            data['loans'].append(loan)
        time.sleep(1)

# recording loans by team in dict
team_loans[i] = data['loans']
if (data['loans']):
    print("===Data added to the team_loan dictionary===")
else:
    print("!!!FAILURE to add data to team_loan dictionary!!!")
# recording data to file when 10 teams are read
if int(i) % 3 == 0:
    file = "data" + str(i - 3) + "-" + str(i) + ".json"
    with open(file, "w") as outfile:
        print("===Now writing team " + str(i) + " data to outfile===")
        json.dump(team_loans, outfile, sort_keys = True, indent = 2, ensure_ascii=True)
        outfile.close()

time.sleep(1)

print ('Done! Check your outfile (data'+ str(i - 3)+'_'+str(i)+'.json)')
```

Indeed an amateurish mess of spaghetti code. Essentially, there is alot of data contained in the api pages, but I only want three elements (IDs). It works at that. The problem is in the structure of the data that I get back, and what is the crux of this post. Here is an example;

```
    {
      "1": [
        {
          "id": 434361,
          "partner_id": 225,
          "team_id": 1
        },
        {
          "id": 431287,
          "partner_id": 122,
          "team_id": 1
        }
      ],
      "2": [
        {
          "id": 1164263,
          "partner_id": 381,
          "team_id": 2
        },
        {
          "id": 1154377,
          "partner_id": 121,
          "team_id": 2
        }
      ],
      "3": [
        {
          "id": 1164263,
          "partner_id": 381,
          "team_id": 3
        },
        {
          "id": 1154377,
          "partner_id": 121,
          "team_id": 3
        }
      ]
    }
```

Why is this JSON structure a problem? Note that each team ID begins a list of key-value pairs, and these lists are all inside the larger JSON dictionary. I do not want a list for every team, I simply want all of the key-value pairs contained inside the lists. This is for database table purposes. The data should look instead like the following;

```
{
  {
    "id": 434361,
    "partner_id": 225,
    "team_id": 1
  },
  {
    "id": 431287,
    "partner_id": 122,
    "team_id": 1
  },
  {
    "id": 1164263,
    "partner_id": 381,
    "team_id": 2
  },
  {
    "id": 1154377,
    "partner_id": 121,
    "team_id": 2
  },
  {
    "id": 1164263,
    "partner_id": 381,
    "team_id": 3
  },
  {
    "id": 1154377,
    "partner_id": 121,
    "team_id": 3
  }
}
```

Now with my limited dictionary knowledge, if I were to delete these team keys (in our example, "1", "2", and "3"), the contents inside their respective lists would also be deleted, resulting in an empty JSON dictionary.

As such I've been attempting to manually delete the strings that makeup the lists (think a regex to strip *'"77" ['* as well as *'} ],'*, but also replacing these strings with the proper strings to maintain JSON validity). This has posed a headache for obvious reasons. I'm working against the data. Yet, I haven't found another way.

I've been unsuccessful thus so far. Please post any clarifying questions, I know it's a lengthy process. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Just get the values and flatten them:

```
import pprint

data = {'1': [{'id': 434361, 'partner_id': 225, 'team_id': 1},
       {'id': 431287, 'partner_id': 122, 'team_id': 1}],
 '2': [{'id': 1164263, 'partner_id': 381, 'team_id': 2},
       {'id': 1154377, 'partner_id': 121, 'team_id': 2}],
 '3': [{'id': 1164263, 'partner_id': 381, 'team_id': 3},
       {'id': 1154377, 'partner_id': 121, 'team_id': 3}]}

pprint.pprint(sum(data.values(), []))
```

Output:

```
[{'id': 1164263, 'partner_id': 381, 'team_id': 3},
 {'id': 1154377, 'partner_id': 121, 'team_id': 3},
 {'id': 1164263, 'partner_id': 381, 'team_id': 2},
 {'id': 1154377, 'partner_id': 121, 'team_id': 2},
 {'id': 434361, 'partner_id': 225, 'team_id': 1},
 {'id': 431287, 'partner_id': 122, 'team_id': 1}]
```

Note this is a list. What you posted as your final output with curly brackets would be a set which is not going to be easy to use here (dictionaries aren't hashable) and probably wouldn't be useful.

Comment: Do you mind explaining this specific use of the pprint method? It doesn't compile as-is and I'm not sure what to change in its place

Comment: It's not important, I just used it to format the output in a certain way. No idea why you're not able to use it but just do what you want with the actual list.

Comment: Reading the data from file and storing as a string, I then run the pprint method and get;
    pprint.pprint(sum(data.values(), []))
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'values'

Comment: Oh, I thought you were starting with a dictionary. `data = json.loads(data)`.

Comment: This looks promising, I'll work with it. If I can move from your answer to solving my problem I'll come back and mark this as correct. Thanks Alex